# how to add background image to carousel in bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

Respected Devs,

I'm new to website development, I wanted to have a carousel effect on hero, so I copied it from [this site](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/carousel/), it's cool though.

I want to reduce the opacity of the hero by adding background-image with linear-gradient of `(0,0,0,0.7)` on both sides to have effect like this,

[image]

so I removed the `src` tag and added the image link in `div` tag, But, it dosen't seem to work, the image doesn't show up on page.

Here's my code

```
<div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active" style="background-image: url('image/must.jpg'), linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,0.7), rgba(0,0,0,0.7));">
      <!--<img src="image/must.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">-->
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img src="image/shelby1.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
    </div>
  </div>
  <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

help me..

Comment: did you try simply giving the opacity css property to the active img tag?

Comment: ok. nvm i just noticed

Comment: create a fiddle(https://jsfiddle.net/) and upload all ur code and share the link.@Cybertronian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The style attributes you used should have worked, but it looks like you did a mess, anyway in order to achieve what you want you have to remove all the stuff and create one from scratch using [getbootstrap.com](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/carousel/) carousel reference and the effect that you want will work by adding the below code.

```
<div class="carousel-item active" style="background-image: url('image/must.jpg'), linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,0.7), rgba(0,0,0,0.7));">
```

There is also one more cool responsive carousel effect repository called **Owl Carousel** on [github](https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/) they also have included how to give different effects on carousel like: *swipe* *drag* *right to left* with continuous loop and it's **fully customizable** check it out, it's cool.

Answer (score 4):

html:

```
 <div class="item">
          <img src="images/pic2.jpg" alt="pic 2">
          <div class="carousel-caption">
            <h1>Web Desgin</h1>
         </div>
            </div>
```

css:

```
.item img {
    position: absolute;
    object-fit:cover;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    min-height: 572px;
    background:rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
}
```

i hope it will help you

Comment: I tried your code, but it came up like this [link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1e0evmc9f9DU4pRzi7bpiiN8FBg3etVIJ)

Comment: try to add this:
.carousel .item {
  height: 550px;
}

Comment: the size changed, but the `rgba` is not coming above image, it's below image [have a look](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1zy1ZQheJ4GZZ54jMVK4-rdhIyjlbI0PY)

Comment: add those to the class in css:
 -webkit-background-size:cover;
    -moz-background-size:cover;
    -o-background-size:cover;
     background-size:cover;

Comment: the black effect on image is still not working with this code css:- `.carousel .item{
    height: 572px;
    background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,0.7), rgba(0,0,0,0.7));
}` [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1zy1ZQheJ4GZZ54jMVK4-rdhIyjlbI0PY/view?usp=drive_open)